# Setting priority above '0' in an angularjs directive prevents transclusion

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In playing around with different directive parameters, I discovered something kind of crazy.

The following directive fails if the priority is set to more than 0

```
app.directive("myDir", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        priority: 0, //must be 0 or transclusion fails
        replace: true, //must be true
        transclude : true, //does this conflict with replace:true?
        template: "<div class='dir-template' ng-transclude></div>"
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DeanIconWeb/CvUpk/

I'm wondering if the problem is the with the replace and transclude both being true.

Can someone please explain this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably a bug, which is closely related to [this one (#1567)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1567) : if the transclude root is the same as the template root and if the replacement is enabled, AngularJS just have a strange behaviour.

It would be friendly to add your problem to the [issue #1567](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1567) in the AngularJS repository.